# AWS Aurora DB max_connection

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to understand what it is and how it's calculated a max_connection for RDS Aurora DB.
At the moment we are trying to use db.t2.small, which based on the AWS documentation allows max_connections = 45

1. Is 45 p/month?
2. Can someone please explain what defines 1 connection? Is it a query to the database?
3. If it's a query, what if a query returns 100 values? Are those counted as connections?

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a database expert, but I can try to answer your questions from what my understanding is.

1)Is 45 p/month?

```
No, the max_connections is not per month but the number of concurrent
connections allowed simultaneously.
```

2) Can someone please explain what defines 1 connection? Is it a query to the database?

```
Connection could either be a query or you trying to manually enter into the
database.

Since for a query to read/write into the database, it needs to open a
connection to the DB, hence it is also counted as one connection, as something
(read here as a piece of code)is connected to your database. It is the same thing
as you opening a client, typing username/password etc and entering into the DB.
```

3) If it's a query, what if a query returns 100 values? Are those counted as connections?

```
The value returned by the query doesn't matter. It can return as many values as it 
like(you need to handle that in your code though). What happens in the code is that
you open a connection and then run a query after that you close that connection.
What happens between when the connection open and closes doesn't affect the number
of connection.

However you need to take care of other parameters while running a long query into a
database. As it could spike your CPU/memory utilization etc. but the number of
connection per query would still be 1.
```